# jqgrid from xml

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When using xml as input to construct a jqgrid, is it possible to get the grid without explicitly mentioning the column names in the options? Is there a way that jqgrid can automatically infer the column names from the xml structure?

Also, if someone can point me to a good sample code for using xml in jqgrid, that would be useful.

Thanks,
DS

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, that what you want is not possible. jqGrid should know which elements of the XML input should be placed in which column.

You can try to analyse the XML which you have with your custom JavaScript code (you can use jQuery to examine the XML contain). After that you can either set `xmlmap` column properties (see [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data)). Another way: you can use XMLT to convert more generic XML data to the standard format used in jqGrid.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely take a look.